# VertX Multiple Futures returning a Future

Tags: future, vert.x, composite, chain

I am trying to call 3 futures, wait for them to complete, process the results and then return all of this also as a Future.  I cant seem to figure out how to "wrap" the 3 futures in a future to be returned so that it doesnt just return immediately.  I am new to vertx.

```
public Future<MyObject> getProjectStatus(int projectId) {

      Future future = Future.future(ar -> {
        MyObject object = new Myobject();

        Future<x> f1 = callf1();
        Future<y> f2 = callf2();
        Future<z> f3 = callf3();

        CompositeFuture cf = CompositeFuture.all(f1, f2, f3);
        cf.onComplete(ar2 -> {
          //Check Succeeds
          if(ar2.succeeded()){
            System.out.println("Completed!");
            //DO FURTHER PROCESSING
          } else {
            System.out.println("Failure " + ar2.cause().getMessage());
          }
        }).map((object));

      });

      return future;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public Future<MyObject> getProjectStatus(int projectId) {

        MyObject object = new Myobject();

        Future<x> f1 = callf1();
        Future<y> f2 = callf2();
        Future<z> f3 = callf3();

        return CompositeFuture.all(f1, f2, f3).onComplete(ar2 -> {
          //Check Succeeds
          if(ar2.succeeded()){
            System.out.println("Completed!");
            //DO FURTHER PROCESSING
          } else {
            System.out.println("Failure " + ar2.cause().getMessage());
          }
        }).map(object);

    }
```

or

```java
public Future<MyObject> getProjectStatus(int projectId) {

      Future future = Future.future(ar -> {
        MyObject object = new Myobject();

        Future<x> f1 = callf1();
        Future<y> f2 = callf2();
        Future<z> f3 = callf3();

        CompositeFuture cf = CompositeFuture.all(f1, f2, f3);
        cf.onComplete(ar2 -> {
          //Check Succeeds
          if(ar2.succeeded()){
            System.out.println("Completed!");
            //DO FURTHER PROCESSING
          } else {
            System.out.println("Failure " + ar2.cause().getMessage());
          }
          ar.complete(object);
        });

      });

      return future;

    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).